# rendering serialized json to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

is there a way to render the hash or json to a variable?

case: 
Rails-app with react/redux, postgres

```
  def index
    start = Time.now
    c = Customer.all.first(1000)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: c,
                             except: [:created_at, :updated_at],
                             include: [{addresses: {except: [:created_at, :updated_at, :country, :canton],
                                                    methods: [:canton_name, :country_name]}},
                                       {latest_order: {only: [:date, :title]}}]
        }
      end
    write_log(c, start)
  end
```

i want to generate a nested hash, e.g. customers, locations, and the latest order, and cache it.

Performance-test for 1000 customers:
code above: 5.3 sec
rendering the same json with
`fast_jsonapi` 4.9 sec
`cache_crispies` 5.2 sec

At the end, the above method ist as fast as the serializers, but easier.

But, for 10.000 customers the time for generating a json (2.5MB) is lasting about 50 seconds, with the rails-render-method.
So, if have to cache it.

Additional Questions:
What are your experiences in cases like this?

Best Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you [jb](https://github.com/amatsuda/jb) gem. It is very fast (slower than `fast_json` but slightly) and `jb` views is a plain ruby, so you get a readable templates without ugly and slow `jbuilder` but with clear structure. You can use cache inside `jb`, so you can cache whole json or part of it, as you want.